# en en query al convertir datetime a date

Tags: sql

tengo un queri que me esta filtrando por fechas, los parámetros  @FECHA_INICIO y @FECHA_FIN son de tipo DATE, pero me esta marcando el siguiente error.

**Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '2025411|2025314' to data type int.**

este es mi filtro

```
    
    WHERE Convert(DATE,A.Paid_Date) between @FECHA_INICIO AND @FECHA_FIN 
    AND @TIPO_MONEDA = A.Currency_Code
```

Comment: me parece que el error es claro te esta diciendo que le estas pasando un valor entero y que se esta rompiendo cuando lo intenta convertir en varchar... puedes ser mas claro en tu pregunta y agregar la estructura de tu tabla y el código que usas para pasarle el valor al query?

Comment: El error no está en esa parte del código. Es probable que algo estés haciendo mal en otra sección del código.

Comment: si de hecho es en un INNER,   ** INNER JOIN Accounting_v_AP_Check I
on A.Check_Links = I.Check_Link**, muchas gracias, ya lo solucione.